# interaction term in multilevel analysis using lmer() function

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, interaction

level 1 variable:

```
income - continuous
```

level 2 variable:

```
state's general whether: three leveled categorical variable: hot/moderate/cool

         used effect coded, and generate two variables because it has three levels.
        (weather_ef1, weather_ef2)  


enrolled in university - binary : yes/no  ( effect coded. yes = -1, no =1)
```

DV:
math score

grouping variable: household

model 1: (fixed slope)

Dv is predicted by income, enrollment, and the interaction between enrollment and income.
in this case,

```
lmer(y~ 1 + income + enrollment +income*enrollment+ (1|householdID), data=data)
lmer(y~ 1 + income + enrollment +income:enrollment+ (1|householdID), data=data)
```

: is it for interaction? or * is it for interaction?

further, do I have to do factor(enrollment)?
or is it okay because it is already effect coded?

model 2: (fixed slope)

DV is predicted by income, weather, and interaction between income and weather

```
lmer( y ~ 1 + income  + weather_ef1 + weather_ef2 + weather_ef1*income
 + weather_ef2*income +(1|houshold_id), data) 

lmer ( y ~ l + income + weather_ef1+ weather_ef2 + weather_ef1:income 
+ weather_ef2:income  + (1|houshold_id), data)
```

Still confusing * is right or: is right.

I think the effect code variables are already effect coded, so I don't have to
do use the factor(weather_ef1) things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation (use `?formula`):

```
The * operator denotes factor crossing: a*b interpreted as a+b+a:b.
```

In other words `a*b` adds the main effects of `a` and `b` and their interaction.  So in your model when you use `income*enrollment` this is the same as `income + enrollment +income:enrollment`.  The two versions you described for each model should give identical results.  You could just have used:

```
lmer(y~ 1 + income*enrollment+ (1|householdID), data=data)
```

which also describes the same model.

If your variables are effect coded then you don't need to use `factor` but be careful about the interpretation of the effects.